# Activate downloaded Magento Tempelate in Localhost (xamp server)

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, localhost, xampp

I have downloaded a theme in Magento CMS and now I want to preview this theme in my Localhost xampp server. For that I have installed Magento on my local server.

But I don't know how to preview the downloaded theme in xampp server.

What I have done:
I have copied the app, js, media and skin folders to the folder into the Magento installation directory but nothing made. Please tell me how I can solve this.

[image]

Comment: go to `admin panel > system > configuration >Design section` set your theme.

Comment: how can i setup there?should i paste some folders like skin and app in magento installation folder before that or not?

Comment: yes that is first part. do that and activate from backend.

Comment: would u please elaborate that part also?

Comment: https://www.irishtitan.com/news/how-manually-install-and-configure-magento-theme-9-easy-steps follow this link

Comment: i followed all the steps and i activated my theme but there is no layout and designing like css

Comment: there must be manual with that theme read that. themes also contain some blocks check for that

Comment: what about file permissions?would u please explain how to set file permissions?

Comment: check the page source if file are loading the all is ok not need of that.

Answer (score 0):

here is simple step to activate your theme

**setp 1.**

Copy your theme folder

> app
>
> Skin
>
> Media
>
> Js

and any other folder include. Paste in magento installed directory.

**step 2.**

go to `admin panel > system > configuration >Design section` set your theme

clear your cache  or delete **var/cache** folder

Comment: i have did this but not getting css in my theme

Comment: view the page source which theme they are getting the file. also check the configuration level may be the theme set on store view

Comment: i have updated question with screnshot

Comment: did you add 777 permission to your file and folder.

Comment: after seen the updated question you are missing the image and block of home kindly read the manual of theme.